# Get-Content with wait parameter doesn't update in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to monitor a file using `Get-Content $path -wait` in Windows Powershell V3.0. Sometimes when I execute this command line in Powershell it will function as expected. But sometimes it will only execute (or at least it seems like) `get-content` but without the `-wait` parameter. Even though the file get's updated it won't be shown in Powershell. If I cancel the command and rerun it it will show the updated file content.

What do I need to do?

**EDIT:** It seems to update blocks after a while. But it's not real-time really.

Comment: Is the process that's writing the file writing everything to disk in realtime? Or does it cache the data in memory up to a point, then flush everything to disk when a threshold (time or size) has been reached? IOW, it's possible that `Get-Content` is doing the best it can, and the writer is what's holding you back.

Comment: As mentioned in the question: As soon as I escape the command and run it again I have an updated file. So it shouldn't be a problem of the writer.

Answer (score 1):

Not allowed to comment (don't have a 50 reputation), so have to give an Answer....

Less for Windows (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/less.htm) with the +F or Shift-F option (http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1024/make-less-behave-like-tail-f.) showed updated file content where PowerShell "get-content $path -wait" did not.

Comment: "+F or Shift-F" are the essential parts of the answer